# How to compare a value from a Dictionary<string, string> in a if statement

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, dictionary

Using the following code, I'm trying to compare one of the parameters of the dictionary in a IF statement but i'm getting syntax errors "Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool"

What would be the way to proceed ? Thank you !

```
Dictionary<string, string>[] responses = Service.Send(Request);
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> response in responses)
            {
if (response["result"] = "0")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Succes !");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error !");
                }
            }
```

result is expected to return 0 if success or 1 if failed

I've tried the following syntax in my IF but they all give me syntax errors:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(response["result"] = "0"))

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response["result"] = "0"))
```

Thank you for your help, i'm not familiar with Dictionaries.

Comment: C# use "==" for comparing equal

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean` takes a single param of what you want to convert, not an expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Thewads OP also have a value only, not an expression.

Comment: This is an example of cargo cult programming. The OP sees the error and just starts trying to convert the whole expression to boolean without thinking about why there's an error in the first place, or even how expressions and if-statements properly work. Please take some time to become familiar with the syntax of C#.

Comment: I feel so stupid about the ==, I was searching way beyond this when the syntax error was so close. Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator while equality operator is `==`.

The line

```
response["result"] = "0"
```

puts `"0"` into the dictionary and returns the assigned value, which is a string `"0"`.
But in C# `if` expects `bool`. Compile-time error says all the truth.

You probably meant

```
if (response["result"] == "0")
```